# Is there ICopyHook.CopyCallback for files or alternative for it?

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, filesystemwatcher, shell-extensions

we use **ICopyHook.CopyCallback** shell extension to detect deletion , moving ,creation of **folders** , but not **files** [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/CopyHook.aspx?msg=1232164) , How to detect if the user is deleting a file from C# Application , or How to handle the delete operation for the user ?
example : the user press Shift + DEL  on f1.txt, then the operating System asks "Are Yuo sure You Want to delete 'f1.txt'? , if the user press 'yes' then the C# application will handle the deletion operation by moving 'f1.txt' to some hidden folder {for example } in transparent way ???

note : I think FileSystemWatcher can NOT do this task ..

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a variant that works for files too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a file system filter driver, which will intercept requests for file deletion or file moving (the file is moved to recycle bin) and will act accordingly.

Note, that as there's no such operation as copying a file on file system level (ICopyHook can catch only operations carried by Explorer itself or via shell API functions), you won't be able to track "copying" using file system filter driver (or by any other means).

Comment: I have installed WinDDK , I tried some samples , what procedure / Event  is being called When user delete a file ???

Comment: @houssam11350 If you are going to write your own kernel-mode driver and don't know kernel-mode basics, it will take you about 6 months (at least) to get the job done.